# How do you set KUBECONFIG to connect to Azure Kubernetes service from github actions deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, github-actions, azure-aks

I am trying to setup a deployment pipeline to configure an Azure Kubernetes service from github actions. I have found steps on the github actions marketplace for configuring various steps however I cannot get any combination of them to work correctly. I keep getting errors saying

> error loading config file
> "/home/runner/work/_temp/kubeconfig_xxxx": yaml: did not find
> expected key

or similar errors saying

> error loading config file couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type struct { APIVersion string json:"apiVersion,omitempty; Kind string json:\kind,omitempty\ }

depending on how I try to pass the kube_config from Terraform. If I run the same environment locally it works so I am assuming there is something wrong with how it is setup on github actions.

Here is my deployment file:

```
name: Deploy

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      <redacted> 

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    env:
      <redacted> 
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: azure/login@v1.1
        with:
          creds: ${{ <redacted> }}

      - name: Generate Terraform backend
        uses: azure/cli@v1.0.3
        with:
          azcliversion: 2.11.1
          inlineScript: |
            <redacted> 

      - uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1.1.0
        with:
          terraform_version: 0.13.0

      - name: Terraform Init
        run: |
          terraform init

      - name: Terraform Plan
        run: |
          terraform plan \
              <redacted> 
              -out=tfplan

      - name: Terraform Apply
        run: |
          terraform apply \
              -auto-approve \
              tfplan

      - uses: azure/setup-kubectl@v1
        with:
          version: 'v1.19.2'

      - uses: azure/setup-helm@v1
        with:
          version: 'v3.3.1'

      - name: Save Config
        run: |
          terraform output kube_config > ./aks.yml

      - name: Set Env
        run: |
          echo ::set-env name=XXX::$(cat ./aks.yml)

      - uses: azure/k8s-set-context@v1
        with:
          method: kubeconfig
          kubeconfig: "${{ env.XXX }}"

      - name: Test
        run: |
          kubectl get pods -o wide
```

I have tried setting KUBECONFIG and getting pods in one step using bash and it also fails. Any ideas what I am missing? Thanks in advance!